# Browserstack-runner tests are timing out with ember-qunit tests

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, browserstack, ember-qunit

I have an `ember-cli` project and all the tests are written using [`ember-qunit`](https://github.com/rwjblue/ember-qunit/). I am using [browserstack-runner](https://github.com/browserstack/browserstack-runner) to run the tests on [Browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com).

browserstack-runner provides the plugin for qunit which I am using. Below is my `browserstack.json`

```
{
    "username": "USERNAME",
    "key": "SECRETKEY",
    "test_framework" : "qunit",
    "test_path": ["tests/index.html"],
    "timeout": "120",
    "browsers": [
        {
            "browser": "chrome",
            "browser_version": "latest",
            "os": "Windows",
            "os_version": "7",
            "browserstack.debug": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Tests are running correctly on browserstack. the only problem is, even after all the tests are run(passed) there is no activity and I am getting timeout error after specified value(120s). 
I am not able to understand why it's happening. I guess it has something to do with plugin which is written specifically for `qunit` and not `ember-qunit`, which is a wrapper arount `qunit`.

Has anyone tried integrating `browserstack` with `ember-cli` project then please guide me.

Comment: My normal qunit tests with timeout set as 120 are working correctly. Is the issue consistent?  How much time are the tests taking to execute ?

Comment: @9ikhan Normal qunit are working for me too. I am using ember-qunit tests. I can see in browserstack automate dashboard that all the  tests are done within 30 seconds max but it doesn't notify browserstack that tests are done. Issues is with browserstack-runner's qunit plugin. It is designed specifically for `qunit`.